# How to display images from different folders in a loop?

Tags: python, image

I have three folders called “group1” “group2” “group3”.
Each folder has a different # of images in them (each in .jpg).

How can I iterate through each file and display the images in a subplot like with plt.subplots? In black and white

I’d like the first row to be labeled “group1”, second to be labeled “group2” and third “group3”

I’ve tried a bunch of different ways but the only way that’s worked has displayed each image one by one on different lines & in dark gray colors/background- not black and white.

I’d post the code but I’ve deleted everything that doesn’t work

[image][image]

So far I’ve been able to display the images from each folder in a single row but because I’m using 2 rows per subplot , the rows are very far apart (see pic). And for some reason you can’t use only 1 row for the subplot function.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"?  Are you actually using matplotlib to do this?

Comment: Hi! Yes I am. Let me post a picture of what I have so far in the post

Comment: Just added pics @Tim Roberts

Comment: "you can't use only 1 row for the subplot function" -- of course you can.  The default value for nrows is 1.  What do you see when you try it?